# List all AD accounts that will expire in exactly "7" days no more, no less.

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to retrieve a list of all AD users who have accounts expiring in 7 days. Not "within". I found a similar question that was answered on here already, but the script only works for within. My script below works but retrieves accounts that will expire "Within" 7 days. I've tried many different ways all of which do not work.

```
$List = Search-Adaccount -AccountExpiring -Timespan 07.00:00:00 | 
Where-Object {$_.DistinguishedName -like "*OU=test,DC=Domain,DC=com"}

$List | export-csv "c:\temp\expiring_accounts.csv"
```

Comment: Please clarify what "exactly" means to you. Is it "in 604 800 seconds" or "during the seventh day from now on"?

Answer (score 1):

Adapting Shay Levy's answer on [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10247334/powershell-find-users-expiring-in-7-days), can you add another condition to the `Where-Object` to put both an upper and lower bound on the expiration date?

```
$NeverExpires = 9223372036854775807;
$ExpireMin = (Get-Date).AddDays(6);
$ExpireMax = (Get-Date).AddDays(8);

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties accountExpires | 
Where-Object {$_.accountExpires -ne $NeverExpires  `
-and [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($_.accountExpires)) -lt $ExpireMax `
-and [datetime]::FromFileTime([int64]::Parse($_.accountExpires)) -gt $ExpireMin }
```

I don't presently have any expiring accounts in the AD environment I have access to, so I don't know if this will work exactly as you're asking.

Comment: I saw Shay's answer, but i did not see a min and a max date and i did not even think to use that or how to add it. That worked great! I appreciate the help. Thank you.

Comment: Question, what are the single quotes for after $neverexpires and $expiremax?

Comment: The backticks are used to indicate a line continuation. Remove the linefeeds and those characters to put it all on a single line.

Comment: alroc, your code is working ok except that it picks up the same users at least 3 times, for 8 days, 7 and 6 days because they fall into that criteria. I am still trying to get just one day. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try the **Free Active Directory Reports** from **adsysnet**.They offer some useful reports(user,computer,ou,contact,group,etc) and functions(move,delete,reset,unlock,send mail,etc) for ad objects.

[Free Active Directory Reports](http://www.adsysnet.com/asn-active-directory-free-admin-helper-features.aspx)